# Using only pull to refresh functionality from ionic

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, material-design, angular-material

I built a Chrome App with Angular Material Design and ported it to android using Cordova for Chrome Apps tool. I included ionic framework into my app and the "pull to refresh" functionality works like a charm with just a couple of lines of changes to my template.

Since ionic is a mobile first framework for developing hybrid mobile apps, it is interfering with the back button actions and scroll bars on android as well as my Chrome App, which is a bit of a problem.

I have tried other plug-ins available on github, but nothing beats ionic's pull-to-refresh.

Like jquery-ui, is it possible to custom download pieces of ionic framework? I just need the ion-refresher component. I am trying to avoid doing a custom hand-rolled one at this point of time.

Any direction regarding this would be really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

for Ion-refresh component you have use $cachefactory function which is defined in angularJS

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your comment. I just want to know if it is even possible to extract modules out of the ionic framework. I just need the ion-refresher module.